# Pandas DataFrame merge summing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two `DataFrames` summing columns value.

```
>>> print(df1)
   id name  weight
0   1    A       0
1   2    B      10
2   3    C      10

>>> print(df2)
   id name  weight
0   2    B      15
1   3    C      10
```

I need to sum `weight` values during merging for similar values in the common column.

```
merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
```

So the output will be something like following.

```
   id name  weight
1   2    B      25
2   3    C      20
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
In [41]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'name']).set_index(['id', 'name']).sum(axis=1)
Out[41]: 
id  name
2   B       25
3   C       20
dtype: int64
```

Comment: How do you merge more than 2? I need union ('outer' merge).

Answer (score 55):

This solution works also if you want to sum more than one column. Assume data frames

```
>>> df1
   id name  weight  height
0   1    A       0       5
1   2    B      10      10
2   3    C      10      15
>>> df2
   id name  weight  height
0   2    B      25      20
1   3    C      20      30
```

You can concatenate them and group by index columns.

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['id', 'name']).sum().reset_index()
   id name  weight  height
0   1    A       0       5
1   2    B      35      30
2   3    C      30      45
```

Answer (score 25):

If you set the common columns as the index, you can just sum the two dataframes, much simpler than merging:

```
In [30]: df1 = df1.set_index(['id', 'name'])

In [31]: df2 = df2.set_index(['id', 'name'])

In [32]: df1 + df2
Out[32]: 
         weight
id name        
1  A        NaN
2  B         25
3  C         20
```

Comment: to avoid `NaN`, you could use `fill_value` for missing names in one of the dataframes: `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`

Comment: If you don't know the common columns, the approach really nice: `(df1 + df2).fillna(df1).fillna(df2)`. Can we do that efficiently ?