# how to sum two dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have  two dataframes

```
tickers                        dt  AAPL  AMC  AMZN  ...  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
0       2021-03-22 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     1     0     0
1       2021-03-23 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     1     0     0
2       2021-03-24 00:00:00+00:00     1    2     0  ...   0     0     0     0
3       2021-03-25 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
4       2021-03-26 00:00:00+00:00     0    2     0  ...   0     4     0     0
```

```
tickers                        dt  AAPL  AMC  AMZN  ...  TH  TSLA  VIAC  WKHS
0       2021-03-19 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
1       2021-03-20 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
2       2021-03-21 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     0     0     0
3       2021-03-22 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     3     0     0
4       2021-03-23 00:00:00+00:00     0    0     0  ...   0     3     0     0
```

I want to sum each row by corresponding row from another dataframe.
You can see that some time from one dataframe doesn't exist in another dataframe. I also want to consider them and include in the new dataframe

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23361783/2612429

Comment: yeah but I also want to consider when they  don't intersect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['dt']).sum().reset_index()

print(df)
```

**PS:** This is ensure all datetimes to exist.

Comment: also, how would I divide one data by another keeping all the time rows

Comment: I request you to kindly ask a separate question as it will involve invalid division operation if the values are missing in either of the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to first merge the dataframes, and then carry out the sum.

```py
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='dt', right_on='dt', how='outer')
```

The column names may end with an '_x' or '_y' to allow you to differentiate. You can then do a normal dataframe sum.

Comment: I tried this one but it remove row  with 2021-03-19 time. And I want to keep it as well

Comment: In that case, I think you can just set `how='outer'`. This will take the union of both keys, so they won't be removed.

Comment: the dataset doesn't have 2021-03-19 00:00:00+00:00 1 2021-03-20 00:00:00+00:00 2 2021-03-21 00:00:00+00:00